# Initializing objects using configuration file at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, configuration-files

I currently writing a project that need to generate different type of object, base on XML configuration file.

Each object that generated is instance of an `IProvidor` interface and and needs to contain several pre-processing, and handling methods that defined by the XML configuration file.
I generated different factories classes for:

1. creating the Provider (which implement the IProvider interface)
2. creating the Pre-Processing operation (I have IPreProcessor interface that all preProcessor class need to implement.
3. the same thing for handling methods (IHandler interface being implemented by several classes).

**Question**

How can I combine all of this into one object in runtime?

Comment: This question is vague. It's unclear to me what you exactly want to know.

Comment: what I'm looking for is that:

Comment: @Steven,  what I'm looking for is that: let's say I have two different providor MailProvider and FTPProvider (both implement IProvider) and two different handlers classes , ZipFilesHandler and RARFileHandle (implement IHandler). Theoretically I have four options of building new objects (MailProvider with ZipFileHandler functionality, MailProvider with RARFileHandler functionality, FTPProvider with ZipFileHandler etc.)  how can I generate the right object in runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Olivier Jacot-Desc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9995111/264697) is absolutely on the right track (+1 for that). The only thing missing from his answer is loading the correct implementations from the configuration.

There are a lot of ways of doing this, for instance by storing the type name in the configuration, but you can also go for a simpler approach, such as storing a simple boolean in the configuration.

```
IProvider providerX = GetProviderFromConfig();
IHandler handlerZ = GetHandlerFromConfig();
IPreProcessor preProcessorY = GetProcessorFromConfig();

var provider = 
    new ProviderWrapper(providerX, preProcessorY, handlerZ);

private static IProvider GetProviderFromConfig()
{
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["provider"] == "mail")
    {
         return new MailProvider();
    }
    else
    {
         return new FtpProvider();
    }
}

// implement GetHandlerFromConfig  just like
// the GetProvider.
```

**UPDATE**

When you have many types to switch between, storing the name of the type might be a better choice:

```
private static IProvider GetProviderFromConfig()
{
    string typeName =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["provider"];

    Type providerType = Type.GetType(typeName);

    return (IProvider)
        Activator.CreateInstance(providerType);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is an example of how to configure this with a DI Container. I'm using [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) (with [extensions](http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Extensions)), but any container will do (although the way to configure it will differ per container):

Registration:

```
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Extensions;

Type providerType = Type.GetType(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["provider"]);

Type handlerType = Type.GetType(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["handler"]);

Type processorType = Type.GetType(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["preProcessor"]);

var container = new Container();

container.Register(typeof(IProvider), providerType);
container.Register(typeof(IHandler), handlerType);
container.Register(typeof(IPreProcessor), processorType);
```

Resolving a provider:

```
var provider = container.GetInstance<IPovider>();
```

Tip: If you use constructor injection, you don't have to wire the types by hand, the container will do this for you. For instance, when your `MailProvider` looks like this, the container is able to inject the needed dependencies (`IHandler`, and `IPreProcessor`) through the constructor:

```
public class MailProvider : IProvider
{
    private readonly IHandler handler;
    private readonly IPreProcessor preProcessor;

    public MailProvider(IHandler handler, 
        IPreProcessor preProcessor)
    {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.preProcessor = preProcessor;
    }

    public void SomeAction() { ... }
}
```

Comment: +1. You are absolutely right. The simplest way of doing this is to use an `if` or a `switch` statement to get the right implementation. In more complex scenarios you could use `Reflection` to generate an appropriate instance. Possibly the XML file could even contain the names of assemblies that would have to be loaded dynamically. And finally an IOC container could be used to do all that.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I was writing an example using an DI container, but decided to leave that out, to keep the answer as simple as possible.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes and Steven, thanks for your answers. the only problem with it is when I have many (in my case few dozen...) of handlers and PreProcessors the if / switch statements will be endless.

Comment: @Steven, thanks for your answers. the only problem with it is when I have many (in my case few dozen...) of handlers and PreProcessors the if / switch statements will be endless

Comment: @Steven, thanks again.Can I instead use AutoFac (or any other DI/IOC toll) to resolve the IProvider (MailProvider, FTPProvider etc.) and injected it's functionality (Handler and PreProcess) as Properties in the IProvider interface? it's looks like the obvious needed solution. if so do you know a good reference / example of how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a wrapper class which implements these interfaces and inject the functionality.

Example interfaces

```
public interface IProvider
{
    string ProvideSomething(int id);
}

public interface IPreProcessor
{
    void PreProcess(string parameter);
}

public interface IHandler
{
    void HandleSomething();
}
```

The wrapper would implement all of these interfaces

```
public class ProviderWrapper : IProvider, IPreProcessor, IHandler
{
    private IProvider _provider;
    private IPreProcessor _preProcessor;
    private IHandler _handler;

    public ProviderWrapper(IProvider provider, IPreProcessor preProcessor, IHandler handler)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _preProcessor = preProcessor;
        _handler = handler;
    }

    #region IProvider Members

    public string ProvideSomething(int id)
    {
        return _provider.ProvideSomething(id);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IPreProcessor Members

    public void PreProcess(string parameter)
    {
        _preProcessor.PreProcess(parameter);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IHandler Members

    public void HandleSomething()
    {
        _handler.HandleSomething();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now, you can instantiate a `ProviderWrapper` with the required functionality according to the configuration file and combine different the interface implementations.

```
var provider = new ProviderWrapper(providerX, preProcessorY, handlerZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create instances of all of these classes as you would normally at runtime, then serialize them to xml. Then when you want to load your "configuration" you just need to de-serialize.

See [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization) for serialization.